# MySQL: how to get average of positive values only?

Tags: mysql, average

Suppose I have INT column, and I am using -1 to signify that no data was available at the time of the INSERT. I'd like to get an AVG of all values of this column that are 0 or larger.

Is this possible?

Thanks.

---

I forgot to mention that I'm doing this alongside other AVG's, so it's select avg(a), avg(b), avg(d) from tab; ... so I can't use b>0... because the others need to use the row data regardless of this one column's data being -1.

It occurs to me though that I could augment the AVG result e.g. if it would normally be (4 + 5 + -1 + -1 + 6) / 5. But if I know how many -1's there are I could "fix" the result to exclude them.

Comment: Ideally true, but the data's in the db already.

Comment: Is your database written in stone?

Comment: @Nerfino: please accept the response if any answered your question well :)

Answer (score 5):

This might help:

If you want to ignore the -1 values from the average:

```
SELECT AVG(`a`), AVG(IF(`b` > -1, `b`, NULL)), AVG(`c`) FROM `t`;
```

If you want to consider the -1 values in the average:

```
SELECT AVG(`a`), AVG(IF(`b` > -1, `b`, 0)), AVG(`c`) FROM `t`;
```

I've assumed dummy column- and table- names and assumed column `b` as the one for which you want to consider only values >= 0. Please feel free to put in names as per your schema.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT AVG(`field`) FROM `table` WHERE `field` >= 0
```

Comment: There should be `>= 0` or `> -1`.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm doing this alongside other AVG's, so it's select avg(a), avg(b), avg(d) from tab; ... so I can't use field>0.

Comment: I had no idea there was an `AVG()` function in MySQL is there something similar in MSSQL?

Answer (score 2):

Please use this:

```
SELECT    AVG(Column),   
 SUM(IF(Column>0))/COUNT(IF(Column>0))
 FROM Table
```

Comment: SELECT AVG(Column), 
    (SELECT AVG(Column) 
     WHERE Column >= 0) as AVG2 ;

Answer (score 0):

Could you do something as such

```
SUM(column) / COUNT(*) as Average FROM 'table' WHERE 'column' >= 0
```

Comment: If I could get a COUNT of the number of non-negative values in the rows, I could solve this pretty handily.