# PHP Mysql to calculate average between datetimes and ignore negative results in average

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Question:  How do I take the query below and have it ignore any timespans in the results that might be negative without excluding relevant data fro the other timespans?  (In other words I can't put the conditions in the WHERE clause because maybe Timespan1 and 2 are good, but timespan3 is negative, but I want to keep them.

Do I put a case statement inside the AVG function?  Is there a more efficient way to run this?

```
    SELECT DATE(tbl.time1) AS 'date',
          AVG((time_to_sec(timediff(tbl.time2 , tbl.time1))/3600) ) AS 'avg_time1',
          AVG((time_to_sec(timediff(tbl.time3 , tbl.time2))/3600) ) AS 'avg_time2',
          AVG((time_to_sec(timediff(tbl.time4 , tbl.time3))/3600) ) AS 'avg_time3',
    FROM tbl
    WHERE DATE(tbl.time1) = '$variable'
    GROUP BY DATE(tbl.time1)
```

I found it using the duplicate Alex mentioned with the principle here:

```
SELECT AVG(`a`), AVG(IF(`b` > -1, `b`, NULL)), AVG(`c`) FROM `t`;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL: how to get average of positive values only?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6612895/mysql-how-to-get-average-of-positive-values-only)

Comment: If you paste queries please make sure they will run. `WHERE AND [...]` is not valid SQL.

Comment: I guess I should have said it isn't if the complete Average is < 0 I want to not show it, but if an individual record in the set is negative throw it out.  For example 2, 3, and -2 should have an average of 2.5 not using the -2 value in the calculation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are looking to use the `HAVING` keyword?

```
SELECT DATE(tbl.time1) AS 'date',
          AVG((time_to_sec(timediff(tbl.time2 , tbl.time1))/3600) ) AS 'avg_time1',
          AVG((time_to_sec(timediff(tbl.time3 , tbl.time2))/3600) ) AS 'avg_time2',
          AVG((time_to_sec(timediff(tbl.time4 , tbl.time3))/3600) ) AS 'avg_time3',
    FROM tbl
    WHERE 
        AND DATE(tbl.time1) = '$variable'
    GROUP BY DATE(tbl.time1) 
    HAVING avg_time1 > 0 AND avg_time2 > 0 and avg_time3 > 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a `case` statement:

```
SELECT DATE(tbl.time1) AS "date",
       (CASE WHEN AVG(time_to_sec(timediff(tbl.time2 , tbl.time1))/3600) >= 0
             THEN AVG(time_to_sec(timediff(tbl.time2 , tbl.time1))/3600)
        END) as avg_time1,
       (CASE WHEN AVG(time_to_sec(timediff(tbl.time3 , tbl.time2))/3600) >= 0
             THEN AVG(time_to_sec(timediff(tbl.time3 , tbl.time2))/3600) 
        END) as avg_time2,
       (CASE WHEN AVG(time_to_sec(timediff(tbl.time4 , tbl.time3))/3600) >= 0
             THEN AVG(time_to_sec(timediff(tbl.time4 , tbl.time3))/3600)
        END) as avg_time3
FROM tbl
WHERE DATE(tbl.time1) = '$variable'
GROUP BY DATE(tbl.time1);
```

This will return `NULL` values rather than negative values, which is what I am guessing you want.

Also, you should only use single quotes for date and string literal values, not for identifiers (such as column names).  Although MySQL permits this syntax, using it usually leads to confusion.